# Задача на Python: элемент списка, который больше предыдущего

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача: задан список с числами. Напишите программу, которая выводит все элементы списка, которые больше предыдущего, в виде отдельного списка. Как я понял надо, например, из заданного списка [1, 5, 1, 5, 1] вывести в итоге [5, 5]
Пробовал решить вот так:

```
a = [1, 5, 1, 5, 1]
for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    n = [a[i]]
    i += 1
    m = [a[i]]
    if m > n:
        n = m
        print(m, end='')
```

На выходе получается:
[5] [5]     а должно быть [5, 5] т.к. надо вывести в виде отдельного списка

Просьба подсказать, что необходимо изменить в коде?

Comment: постарайтесь избегать в тексте ненужных сокращений, чтобы не приходилось гадать, что именно вы имели в виду.

Comment: res = [a[i] for i in range(1, len(a)) if a[i] > a[i-1]] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [1, 5, 1, 5, 1]
answer = []

for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if a[i] < a[i+1]:
        answer.append(a[i+1])

print(answer)
```

Вам надо создавать массив, т.к. это написано в условии задачи

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1, 5, 1, 5, 1]
m = [j for i, j in zip(a, a[1:]) if j > i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так

```
a = [1, 5, 1, 5, 1]
c= []
for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    n = a[i]
    i += 1
    m = a[i]
    if m > n:
        c.append(m)
print(c)
```